# Open a fragment from navigation bar using if (id == R.id.nav_profile)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have created all of my fragments and layouts, I would have previously used a switch statement in eclipes when I last created an app but now it prompts me to use  if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        } else if (id == R.id.MakeUp)

Can anybody tell me the correct code for selecting an option in my navigation drawer and opening a new fragment?

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
    } else if (id == R.id.MakeUp) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Hairdressers) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_Beauticians) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
   }
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
       <item android:id="@+id/nav_profile" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Profile" />
    <item android:id="@+id/MakeUp" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Make-Up" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_Hairdressers" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Hairdressers" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_Beauticians" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Beauticians" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_send"      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

```
10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager: No   view found for id 0x7f0c0076 (com.example.james.nixr:id/makup_layout) for   fragment makup{28f4e84 #0 id=0x7f0c0076}
10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity c3caaf7 State:
10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:          mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
```

10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true

Blockquote

```
    10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
     10-22 02:20:09.776 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@3f08d66d
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@3f08d66d
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3f15c794 V.E..... ...   0,0-1080,1920}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{30383fe7 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1920}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{d66b2a2 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020436}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{2f8d423d V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1920}
10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.internal.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{181fa32 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1920 #7f0c0057 app:id/action_bar_root}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:              android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewStubCompat{a739b33 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0  #7f0c0058 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:             
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout{333ef383 V.E..... ... 0,0-    1080,1920 #1020002 android:id/content}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:               android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{1a51c900 VFED.... ... 0,0-1080,1920 #7f0c006b app:id/drawer_layout}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout{1610c539 V.ED.... ... 0,0-  1080,1920}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout{451877e V.E..... ... 0,75-1080,243}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{377344df V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,168 #7f0c006d app:id/toolbar}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.TextView{3caf7bf5 V.ED.... ... 180,43-297,124}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.ImageButton{1e8a752c VFED..C. ... 0,0-168,168}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{365628f2 V.E..... ... 972,0-1080,168}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{555b43 VFED..C. ... 0,12-108,156}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                   
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager: android.widget.RelativeLayout{22fa9d8a V.E..... ... 0,243-1080,1920}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{23714ffb V.ED.... ... 48,48-273,105}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                      android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton{34bfb818 VFED..C. ...   864,1704-1032,1872 #7f0c006e app:id/fab}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                 android.support.design.widget.NavigationView{1a48e271 V.E..... ... 0,0-888,1920 #7f0c006c app:id/nav_view}
10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView{3a6d0856 VFED.V.. F.. 0,0-  888,1920 #7f0c0072 app:id/design_navigation_view}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{14043dc4 V.E..... ... 0,0-888,504 #7f0c0071   app:id/navigation_header_container}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                        android.widget.LinearLayout{1a3834ad V.E..... ... 0,0-888,480}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{34c953e2 V.ED.... ... 48,78-192,270 #7f0c0078 app:id/imageView}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1413c373 V.ED.... ... 48,270-840,375}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2fe97230 V.ED.... ... 48,375-592,432 #7f0c0079 app:id/textView}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{29327992 V.ED..C. ...   0,504-888,648}
    10-22 02:20:09.786 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{4746f63 V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{2915c760 V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{327a9cde V.ED..C. ..P 0,648-888,792}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{bb49ebf V.ED.... ..P 48,0-  840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{afff98c V.E..... ..P 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{158fa8ea V.ED..C. ... 0,792-888,936}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{29e67db V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
    10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{f792278 V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{325c209a V.ED..C. ... 0,936-888,1080}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{1444fdcb V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{3cb619a8 V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{124bac66 V.ED..C. ... 0,1080-888,1224}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{15a3aba7 V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager: android.widget.FrameLayout{3f272854 V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.FrameLayout{24b18d8d V.E..... ... 0,1224-888,1251}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.view.View{c86b42 V.ED.... ... 0,24-888,27}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{2b67589 V.ED.... ... 0,1251-888,1395}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{3dbca5b5 V.ED..C. ... 0,1395-888,1539}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{22cde44a V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{2874efbb V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{2e5ee831 V.ED..C. ... 0,1539-888,1683}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{300dfb16 V.ED.... ... 48,0-840,144 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{178cc97 V.E..... ... 840,0-840,144 #7f0c0075 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.james.nixr, PID: 12351
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0076 (com.example.james.nixr:id/makup_layout) for fragment makup{28f4e84 #0 id=0x7f0c0076}
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:896)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
10-22 02:20:09.796 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    10-22 02:20:11.116 12351-12351/com.example.james.nixr I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12351 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Why can't you use a switch statement here? You would just do `switch(id)...case R.id.Makeup:` ,etc.

Comment: I have tried this many of times, this is my first time using the nav drawer I was under the impression it worked different to nav tabs.

Comment: So what is your question then? What part of this is not working? A `switch` statement would work just fine there. So if it's not, then you're not implementing the switch correctly.

Comment: I have only used the int position switch statement, that gave me all sort or errors.

Comment: I have input this, is there code i am missing inbetween?                                          switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.nav_profile:

        return true;

    case R.id.nav_hairdrerssers:

        return true;

    case R.id.makeup:

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Switch should work great, is your question about using Fragments and FragmentManager? Here's a good tutorial for that using NavigationView:
 http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Comment: This is a really good article if I was starting from scratch, I have used the android navigation drawer template, I tried the switch from that tutorial and it wont recognise the fragment tag, I am unsure how these really work to be honest, ive been reading about them all day to try and understand them.

Comment: "Switch" or "if else" will have the same behavior, so is your problem that it wont enter inside those statements? Can you give me any other detail? Or your code where you use the FragmentManager?

Comment: i am unsure what code goes inside the if else to open the new fragment, that is my question, im guessing i need more than;

Comment: if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.MakeUp) {
            return true;

Answer (score 0):

OK so judging from the various comments you've left on this question, I'm guessing your ACTUAL question was, how to add a new Fragment to the view when you get a call to `onNavigationItemSelected()`. You would do something like this...

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); //or getSupportFragmentManager() if you're using support library
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

MakeupFragment makeupFragment = MakeupFragment.newInstance();
transaction.add(R.id.container_that_holds_fragment, makeupFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Or if one Fragment is already showing and you need to replace it...

```
HairdresserFragment hairdresserFragment = HairdresserFragment.newInstance();
transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_that_holds_fragment, hairdresserFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Is this the info you were looking for?

---

**EDIT: In response to comments below...**
If you are getting the error `cannot resolve method newInstance()` or something similar, it means you have not defined this method in your fragment. Make sure your fragment has the following method defined...

```
public static YourFragment newInstance() {
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    return fragment;
}
```

Your fragment should instantiate itself using this static method, then pass back the created fragment to whoever called for it. Once you have this method implemented in your fragment, you simply call `YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance();`

Comment: I have put your first piece of code in and I get an error with, makup makeupNew = makup.newInstance();

Comment: What's the error? Remember that `newInstance()` is a static method. So you call it on the class itself, not the object. And of course, you must have a static newInstance method defined in your fragment as well. Let me know what the error says and I'll try to help.

Comment: This is the error "Error:(91, 32) error: cannot find symbol method newInstance()"  I have the code inside  "public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)"

Comment: This is the Instance I have in my Fragment " public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.makup_layout, container, false);
                return rootview;"

Comment: See my edits above. You do not have `newInstance()` defined in your Fragment.

Comment: I have updated the code to what you provided, the code gives me no errors but the app crashes, its something to do with the makup_layout, shall I put my logcat up ?

Comment: You can if you'd like. It sounds like you need to do some reading on the basics of Fragments and how they work. You should read [this Google guide on using Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) to better understand my code and how your full Fragment code should look.

Comment: I have added my logcat to the question, for some reason it didnt go into the question properly formatted, I have read the tutorial you send in your previous comment it was very useful thanks,  although I still haven't found a solution,.

Comment: I edited your logcat so it will be formatted correctly. The changes will show once my edits are peer reviewed. As for your error, I see an error stating: `No view found for id 0x7f0c0076 (com.example.james.nixr:id/makup_layout) for fragment makup`. This means that you are trying to pass in a layout xml file instead of a specific view, I'm assuming in the `replace` method. You must pass in the container view WITHIN a layout that will hold your fragment. So for example, a `RelativeLayout` or something similar inside your Activity that's holding the Fragment.